# Is this a pre-noun adjectival?

Tags: meaning

Does ような work as a pre-noun adjectival in this two sentences?

> 1. これに匹敵する**ような**車は日本ではずっと高いでしょう。
> 2. 各大会で多くの方があなたのグッズを身にまとい一大ブームとなっており、かつてのnWoに匹敵する**ような**状態となってます。

Because when I look for sentences using ような I mostly sentences like these:

> 1. あの人を見たような気がしました。
> 2. 彼は、何も言いたくないような、押し黙った表情をしてる。

Which seem to be just よう(noun) + な and not pre-noun adjectival.
Or should I treat all this 匹敵するような as one phrase?

Comment: All ようなs modify nouns 車, 状態, 気 and 表情.

Comment: @user4092 you are right, but for some reason I'm not sure whether to parse it as nWoに匹敵するような 状態 or nWoに匹敵する ような状態

Comment: It's the former. That よう doesn't work alone.

Answer (score 1):

Top two is comparable in quality.

1. I suppose that the Cars similar to this in quality are way more expensive in Japan.
2. In every tournament, a lot of people wearing your merchandises is making huge phenomenon which is as popular as nWo used to be.

Bottom two is an assumption.

1. I have felt as if I had seen that person.
2. He is poker-faced as if he would not want to say anything.